# How do I systematically replace text within mustache tags in a large body of text?

Tags: regex, node.js, mustache

I have quite a few templates that utilize mustache tags to determine where to place user data.  These templates are stored as a string.

When I call the render function within mustache, I feed in a complex JSON object that contains a number of arrays of both strings and subdocuments.

I incorrectly declared within the mustache tag to use a particular element within array like so:

```
{{dataElementArray[2].subElement}}
{{anotherElement.dataArray[1]}}
```

Instead I would like to change all occurrences within each template to the proper mustache syntax for addressing elements like so:

```
{{dataElementArray.2.subElement}}
{{anotherElement.dataArray.1}}
```

What's the best way to systematically go through each template (represented as a string) and use regex's to change what is in each tag?  I have over 50 templates, most of them hundreds of lines long with hundreds of tags within each one.

I am using JavaScript/Node.js for this app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a tough (but not impossible) task to do with a single regular expression.  Fortunately, there's no reason we have to do it with a single one.  A much easier (and more robust) approach is to use two regular expressions: one to match replacement tags (things contained in `{{curly brackets}}`) and another to replace instances of array indexers with dot indexers.  Here's my solution:

```
s.replace( /\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g, function(x){          // this grabs replacement tags
  return x.replace( /\[(\d+)\]/g,'.$1' )});      // this replaces array indexers
```

Note: I have not analyzed this solution with the [entire mustache syntax](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html), so I cannot guarantee it will work if you're using more than the standard tags.

Comment: Awesome.  This seemed to work perfectly!  I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VrbV4/) for others to see this code in action.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

## Description

This expression will match the first square bracketed numbers inside the mustache brackets, it also validates the square brackets are followed by either a dot or the close mustache bracket.

Use this regex: `(\{\{[a-z.]*[a-z])\[(\d+)\](?=\.|\})([a-z.]*\}\})`

With this replacement: `$1.$2$3`

[image]

## Javascript Code Example:

http://www.myregextester.com/?r=f9e362af

**Sample Input**

```
{{dataElementArray[2].subElement}}
{{anotherElement.dataArray[1]}}
{{alreadyFormatted.dataArray.1}}
```

**Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var re = /(\{\{[a-z.]*[a-z])\[(\d+)\](?=\.|\})([a-z.]*\}\})/;
  var sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
  var replacementpattern = "$1.$2$3";
  var result = sourcestring.replace(re, replacementpattern);
  alert("result = " + result);
</script>
```

**After Replacement**

```
{{dataElementArray.2.subElement}}
{{anotherElement.dataArray.1}}
{{alreadyFormatted.dataArray.1}}
```

Comment: I just tried your example, and it is problematic because it will only replace the last array indexer.  For example, your solution will fail on this input: `{{outer[3].inner[2]}}`.  Also, it will fail if there are more than one tag in a line (for example, just put your sample input on one line instead of on multiple lines).  I believe my solution is more robust.

Comment: That edge case wasn't discussed in the OP.

Comment: The OP doesn't mention multiple array indexers in the same tag, it's true, but you can't infer from the OP that there won't be multiple tags in a single line.

Comment: There are edge cases that either solution will fail. For example yours will match anything including `str = '{{ I have [1] text here}}'` which you can't infer doesn't exist based on the OP.

Comment: It's true, and that's why I added the caveat that I didn't scour the Handlebars spec to account for every possible type of tag.  I was just aiming for something robust enough that it would cover the common cases.

Comment: Yes -- although I didn't mention multiple array indexers in the same tag in my original post, I did have that as a test case in my jsFiddle referenced above.  I do recognize that the `'{{ I have [1] }}` case will fail, but fortunately, for my purposes, I don't have that type of text in my current templates I am modifying.